# Angular 5 router resolver not getting data

Tags: angular

Currently, I've developed a simple UI to allow an user to select an option from a list. The issue now is that the angular service I created deliver the data after page renders, so the dropdown never takes the data from the service.

At the beginning I've been using an endpoint call to an api service from the angular service, that delivers the data to fill the dropdown, and if I use this locally works fine. The bug arise when I try to get the info from a remote server error like mLab or MongoDB Atlas service. In this last case, the info arrives but after the page renders and the dropdown never show the options.

Reading around the internet and documentation, I found that the use of a angular resolver could help on this getting the data previously to load the page, but I couldn't find how it works until now. Maybe anyone can help me on this?

**docs-list.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import swal from 'sweetalert2';
import { DocumentationService } from '../documentation.service';
import { Logger } from '../logger.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-docs-list',
    templateUrl: './docs-list.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./docs-list.component.css']
})
export class DocsListComponent implements OnInit {

  urlSelected = '';
  docsAvailable = [
  ];

  constructor(private router: Router,
              private route: ActivatedRoute,
              private http: HttpClient,
              private documentationService: DocumentationService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.docsAvailable = this.route.snapshot.data['docs'];
    console.log(this.docsAvailable);
  }

  onChange(value) {
    // console.log(value);
    this.urlSelected = value;
  }
}
```

**documentation-resolver.service.ts**

```
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
 import { Router, Resolve, ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
 import { DocumentationService } from './documentation.service';
 import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
 import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

 @Injectable()
 export class DocumentationResolver implements Resolve<any> {
    constructor(
        private documentationService: DocumentationService,
        private router: Router
    ) { }

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<any> {
    return this.documentationService.getDocs().map(docs => {
        console.log(docs);
        return docs;
    });
}
}
```

**documentation.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Logger } from './logger.service';

const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};

@Injectable()
export class DocumentationService {

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private logger: Logger) { }

  getDocs(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get('documents');
  }

}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { DocsListComponent } from './docs-list/docs-list.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { Logger } from './logger.service';
import { DocumentationService } from './documentation.service';
import { DocumentationResolver } from './documentation- 
    resolver.service';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '',
     component: DocsListComponent,
    resolve: {
       docs: DocumentationResolver
    }
  }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
     DocsListComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(
      appRoutes,
      {enableTracing: true}
    )
  ],
   providers: [
     Logger,
     DocumentationService,
     DocumentationResolver
   ],
   bootstrap: [
     AppComponent
   ]
 })
 export class AppModule { }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share your code by http://stackblitz.com?

Comment: any console error?

Comment: Mapping the response to an empty object doesn't sound useful.

Comment: You were right, I changed the empty object and now it returns a value BUT the interface still not takes the data.

Answer (score 0):

You are mapping response to empty object

```
return this.documentationService.getDocs().map(user => {});
```

why (most probably) document would be user is another mistery. Please revise your code for such errors.

Also if you would start using type controll and stop using `<any>` everywhere but concrete types, such error would be picked up by a compiler explaining to you that `{}` does not match signature for type `X`

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I've changed the empty object. In the other hand, I return an observable with any because I'm not using an object, I'll try to change it. In the other hand, now I get a value returning an object from the mapping response but I still doesn't achive the dropdown gets the data returned.